# Add a new entry in KDialog "Save as" window

Tags: kde, dolphin

I have running KDE Plasma for a few months now, and I have been able to fix some minor issues with the Google Drive integration in Dolphin. The only thing I cannot get done is to add an entry to my Google Drive in the standard KDialog "save as" when, for example, I want to save a picture in my computer from the web. I got it in Dolphin:

[Dolphin Drive links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhLvV.png)

But I can't get same result in KDialog:

[KDialog links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U69h9.png)

Any help with this?

Thanks a lot.

Borja.

Comment: What version of Ununtu?

Comment: Operating System: KDE neon 5.20
KDE Plasma Version: 5.20.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.78.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-59-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-3610QM CPU @ 2.30GHz
Memory: 11.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVE4